# Adding a modifier class to parent/root selector in nested SCSS to modify styling

Tags: html, css, sass

In a nested group of SCSS, is it possible to move up a level and apply a modifier class to the parent to overwrite styling?

For example, I have the following SCSS where an image is added to the before/after classes. I need to change the images on a different `.btn--` styling. So essentially compiled the CSS would look a bit like `.btn--ghost .label:before, .btn--ghost .after {}`.

There is more styling to this but I've just stripped it out for this example so it's not a wall of code.

```
.btn--arrow {
    
    .label {

        &:before,
        &:after {
            background: url(../img/icon-arrow--white.svg) no-repeat 0 0;
        }

        &.btn--ghost & {
                
            &:before,
            &:after {
                background: url(../img/icon-arrow.svg) no-repeat 0 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have successfully achieved this with the SCSS outside of the `.label`, so directly under `.btn--arrow` (below) but out of curiosity and better understanding I'd be interested to know if it's achievable in the first example I gave.

```
.btn--arrow {
    
    .label {
        
        &:before,
        &:after {
            background: url(../img/icon-arrow--white.svg) no-repeat 0 0;
        }
    }
    
    &.btn--ghost {
        
        .label {
            
            &:before,
            &:after {
                background: url(../img/icon-arrow.svg) no-repeat 0 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried moving the `&` around and using stuff like `@at-root` but without any success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't _believe_ what you are seeking is possible. Honestly, if I'm understanding correctly, it sounds like it any DRY-ness gained from the solution would lead to some painful maintainability problems. That said, perhaps I simply am not understanding your use case.  FWIW, you might be able to achieve the desired optimization with a [`@mixin`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin) or an [`@extend`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend).

Comment: Thanks, yeah I was thinking it's probably more hassle than it's worth! I think the later solution is fine. But I'm a bit rusty when it comes to writing code so was wondering if I'd missed/forgotten something. Thanks for the reply @AlexanderNied! :)

Comment: Glad to help-- happy coding!

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69231058/how-to-use-n-syntax-in-sass/69251723#69251723) covers your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can qualify a selector by putting `&` to the right of the intended parent of the selector. Wrapping it in `#{}` allows you to place it directly beside that parent.

The @at-root rule causes everything proceeding to be emitted at the root instead of using regular nesting.

If you use both and the `#{}`, I think you can achieve what you are looking for.

```
.flashlight {
    .light {
        background: yellow;

        @at-root .dead-battery#{&} {
            background: transparent;
        }

        .daytime &{
            background: transparent;
        }
    }
}
```

This would compile to:

```
.flashlight .light {
    background: yellow;
}
.dead-battery.flashlight .light {
    background: transparent;
}
.daytime .flashlight .light {
    background: transparent;
}
```