# How to use `^[N]` syntax in sass

Tags: sass, stylus

I migrated from stylus to sass. In stylus, you can use [^[N]](https://stylus-lang.com/docs/selectors.html#partial-reference) for partial quoting. How to do this in sass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stylus feature [Partial Reference](https://stylus-lang.com/docs/selectors.html#partial-reference) has no direct equivalent in SCSS/SASS.
In SASS the `&` always contains the complete parent selector and there is no feature to retrieve only a part of it.

There are however...

- the special `@at-root` to ditch the parent and...
- a combined technique to capture the parent selector in a local-scoped variable and to use [string interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) to create a selector from it.

See what it does:

```
.foo {
    .bar { color: red; }
    @at-root .bar { display: block; }
}

renders to:

.foo .bar { color: red; }
.bar { display: block; }
```

and

```
.foo {
    $block-class: &;
    &__header {
        font-size: medium;
        @at-root #{$block-class}.large-header & { font-size: large; }
    }
    &__footer {
        color: red;
    }
}

renders to:

.foo__header {
  font-size: medium;
}
.foo.large-header .foo__header {
  font-size: large;
}

.foo__footer {
  color: red;
}
```

A word of caution: I would not recommend to use such elaborate SCSS gymnastics to impress and confuse anyone who ever needs to read your code. Really, just keep it simple. Sometimes it is the right thing to do to just repeat a selector in the code. No harm done.