# SCSS parent selector not works

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a container and three parts in it. I want to make unvisible thirth part while addind class to the parent container. But my codes not works...

Here is the HTML code:

```
<section id="parts" class="two-parts">
    <div id="partOne">...</div>
    <div id="partTwo">...</div>
    <div id="partThree">...</div>
</section>
```

Here is the SCSS code:

```
#partThree{
    display: block;

    .two-parts &{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

I want to hide `#partThree` div, when `#parts` div has `.two-parts` class.

Guys! I found the problem. I checked the output of Scss to Css, and here is the Css output:

```
.two-parts body #parts #partThree {
  display: none;
}
```

It should be `#parts.two-parts #partThree`. But why is that goes to the top of all elements?

Comment: Yeah... When you write `&.two-parts` that means in css `#partThree.two-parts`. 
Also, I edited my mistake when I wrote the quesiton.

Comment: @David no, the syntax is correct. `.two-parts &` results in `.two-parts #partThree`

Comment: Your code works: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0poL9c3b/)

Comment: @GertB. but not works... Why?

Comment: Is it nested in another selector? the code should work fine

Comment: Gotcha. I'm no SCSS person. That syntax doesn't make sense to me in terms of vanilla CSS, but hey. You learn something new every day.

Comment: @David true, This is one of the reasons I like to use SCSS, I don't need to type the same selector multiple times :-)

Comment: I'm writing SCSS for over 10 years now, but I never realized that you could put the ampersand not at the start of the sub clause... and it still makes sense! o.O (It could turn out to be a maintenance nightmare for colleagues that aren't aware of it, though. ^^)

Comment: @orithena A lot of developers use it that way, you can put the `&` anywhere in the selector, but indeed i would try to avoid putting it in other places than at the beginning or the end for easier maintenance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use \`^\[N\]\` syntax in sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69231058/how-to-use-n-syntax-in-sass)

Answer (score 0):

As I have answered in your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69281271/how-to-select-one-step-bigger-parent-in-scss):

It looks like your code is wrapped by a `body`-tag and a `#parts`-tag. This means you need to change your code to this:

```
#partThree{
    display: block;
}

&.two-parts #partThree {
    display: none;
}
```

The `&` takes EVERYTHING before the current line. So if your final SCSS is:

```
body {
    #parts {
        #partThree {
            display: block;

            .two-parts & {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the `&` will add `.two-parts` before everything else, and make it:

```
.two-parts body #parts #partThree {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way to achieve what you need is by setting `.two-parts` and `#partThree` as siblings, and apply ~ css operator.

```
<style>
  #partThree {
    display: block;

  .two-parts ~ {
    display: none;
  }
}
<style>

<section id="parts">
    <div id="partOne">...</div>
    <div id="partTwo" class="two-parts">...</div>
    <div id="partThree">...</div>
</section>
```

this will only work if #partThree and .two-parts siblings and .two-parts comes before.

Comment: This is not Scss and I already know this way. I want to write in Scss.

Comment: I edit the code its in Scss now.

Comment: Maybe this one would work but no, it's not working. Thank you anyway.

Comment: no, the syntax is correct.`.two-parts &` results in `.two-parts #partThree`