# Using the CSS sibling selector (+) along with the SCSS parent selector (&) within a nested structure

Tags: css, sass, nested, node-sass

I am often trying to style the next sibling of an element with SCSS, within a nested structure as the following:

```html
  <div class="grand_parent">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="parent__child-1"></div>
      <div class="parent__child-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
/* SCSS Code */

.grand_parent {
  .parent {
    &__child-1 + &__child-2 {
     /* do some stuff */
    }
  }
}
```

The output of the above SCSS (using `node-sass` for compilation) is similar to the following. Which isn't working unfortunately.

```css
/* CSS Output */

.grand__parent .parent .parent__child-1 + .grand__parent .parent .parent__child-2 {  
  /* do some stuff */
}
```

What I am expecting is the following output, which isn't possible since the [parent selector](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector) returns the complete parent with the nested structure.

```css
/* Expected CSS Output */

.grand__parent .parent .parent__child-1 + .parent__child-2 {
  /* do some stuff */
}
```

This output can be generated when not using the second parent selector in along with the sibling selector, like so `&__child-1 + .parent__child-2`. Which is the method I am using. But I think it would be more readable and convenient if I could also use the parent selector here.

**Don't get me wrong:** I think this is definitely the correct behaviour, since it maintains the scoping of the parent. But I would like to know if there's a workaround for that or of I did something wrong … I've often stumbled over this problem and always solved it without really thinking about it.

Comment: You could go with `$root: '.parent';
    #{$root}__child-1 + #{$root}__child-2 {...}`, but I know that it isn't perfect.

Comment: Thanks @AmauryHanser. That seems like a doable workaround – that at least prevents from the necessity of using the specific selector inside the structure again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use \`^\[N\]\` syntax in sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69231058/how-to-use-n-syntax-in-sass)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I think this is a similar approach as proposed by @AmauryHanser.
Maybe I should use stylus more often though … ^^

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you the expected CSS:

```
.grand__parent {
  .parent {
    .parent__child-1 {
      & + .parent__child-1 {
        //styles here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sramirez0. But this isn't really different from my already proposed solution: `&__child-1 + .parent__child-2`.